# How do I do a jQuery toggleClass in Volt?

Tags: ruby, opalrb, voltrb

I'm playing around with [Volt](http://voltframework.com) and currently trying to do a simple toggleClass for a sidebar in my Volt app (with no luck). Here is a code sample.

app/main/views/main.html

```
<:Title>
  {{ view main_path, "title", {controller_group: 'main'} }}

<:Body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="btn btn-default sidebar-toggler">Toggle Sidebar</div>
        <:volt:notices />
        {{ view main_path, 'body', {controller_group: 'main'} }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

app/main/assets/js/sidebar.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sidebar-toggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  });
});
```

When clicking on `div.sidebar-toggler` a `toggled` class should be added to `div#wrapper` ... It doesn't, there maybe another way to do this with Volt.

The code above is not working. 
What's the **good Volt way** to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In volt, you would typically make the toggle state a "[reactive accessors](http://docs.voltframework.com/en/docs/reactive_accessors.html)" on the controller, then use bindings to update the class state.   Since controllers are the context for bindings, we can check the state of the reactive_accessor in an if binding.

in the controller:

```
module Main
  class MainController < Volt::ModelController
    reactive_accessor :toggled

    def toggle_sidebar
      self.toggled = !toggled
    end
    ....
```

in the view:

```
...
<div class="btn btn-default sidebar-toggler {{ if toggled }}toggled{{ end }}" e-click="toggle_sidebar">Toggle Sidebar</div>
...
```

When we call the self.toggled = method, it changes the state and reactively updates any bindings using that data.  The e-click calls the toggle_sidebar method on the controller.  The common Volt way to do something simple like this is to put the `if` directly into the view.  We could also put it into a method that returns a string and bind to that.

```
def toggled_class
  toggled ? 'toggled' : ''
end

....

<div class="btn btn-default sidebar-toggler {{ toggled_class }}" e-click="toggle_sidebar">Toggle Sidebar</div>
```

Hopefully that helps, I can clarify more if you need.